# What is the purpose of the "Spotlight" on Careers?

Tags: support, jobs

There's this nice section at the bottom right of the Careers website that is titled Spotlight and features a company. It's very nice, but the problem is, I can't figure out what it's purpose is. It doesn't link to a job posting as far as I can tell. Is it just advertising, or does it have another purpose?

Answer (score 3):

Dude, it's an advertisement for that company!  Companies want to attract top talent.  The "career" site is one of the ways Joel & Company are going to monetize S.O.

Comment: this comment is brought to you by Barnes & Noble.

Comment: Notice the subtle subliminal message?  Jeff is shrewd but effective! ;)